# less.js: Use custom import function

Tags: javascript, less

less.js is using an internal xhr() function to load @imported .less files dynamically via ajax.

I want to know if there is anything I can do the hand a custom function over to the less parser to get the imported files loaded through this function and NOT through the default loading function.

As a wild example: I may have stored the .less file I want to import in my localStorage and want less.js to load it from there, instead via AJAX.

Comment: Mildly off topic, but I highly recommend not relying on client-side LESS compilation -- it's a little wonky in some *ahem* ie *ahem* browsers and takes a bit of time on the client end for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a fork and override or change `loadStyleSheets` and have it check in localStorage first.

Since the entire system is designed to run a closure it'll be hard (if not impossible -- I've never tried to modify a closure from outside the closure) to make any additions post-library load.